# I can't seem to move the location of a Picture box in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I'm trying to make it so that when I press the up arrow, it moves the picture box up, the down arrow moves down, ect. But I can't seem to get it to work. It is giving me the error:

> *Can't modify the return value of
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Location' because it is not a variable*

This is my code:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            ImgGuy.Location.Y--;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            ImgGuy.Location.Y++;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            ImgGuy.Location.X--;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            ImgGuy.Location.X++;
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to recreate new `Location`:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
        Point l;

        if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            l = new Point(ImgGuy.Location.X, ImgGuy.Location.Y - 1);
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            l = new Point(ImgGuy.Location.X, ImgGuy.Location.Y + 1);
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            l = new Point(ImgGuy.Location.X - 1, ImgGuy.Location.Y);
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            l = new Point(ImgGuy.Location.X + 1, ImgGuy.Location.Y);
        }

        ImgGuy.Location = l;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did solve the error I was having, however, it gave me two new ones:

"Cannot implicitly convert 'int' to 'System.Drawing.Point'"
And
"Only assingnent, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

Comment: @Bondca The perils of using `l` as a variable name. It looks too much like `1`. (I'm guessing that's what happened - you used a one instead of an ell)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ImgGuy.Location = new Point(ImgGuy.Location.X+1, ImgGuy.Location.Y+1) // etc
```

The problem is that `Location` returns a copy of the location.

Alternatively, set `Control.Left` and `Control.Top` instead.

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick (Matthew Watson's answer). Thank you to everyone though! Great help

Answer (score 0):

You need to produce a new point

In this case X is increased aka move left

```
Pic.Location = new Point(Pic.Location.X + 1, Pic.Location.Y);
```